# Auto commit on file modify with SVN (or git)?

Tags: svn, git, continuous-integration

I've been reading and searching for a solution for a couple of days but haven't found anything that suits my needs.

We have frequently updated sites being updated by designers and developers that most of the time don't commit their changes to SVN.

I'm looking at continuous integration type solutions where, when a "versionned" file on the staging server gets updated, it is automatically committed to SVN.

CruiseControl and other tools I've looked at don't do this; is there a tool that does this or a better process we could use?

Thanks for any help!

Chris

Comment: See this question on Programmers: [Easy way of engaging non-programmers (i.e. designers) into using version control?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/43819/easy-way-of-engaging-non-programmers-i-e-designers-into-using-version-control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like that you said "better process" because the answer there is yes.

Have your designers and everyone work from the repo. It doesn't matter if you choose SVN or git or something else, but make that the "authoritative" copy. Doing so will eventually save you headaches as you'll have a clear history of all changes, and can always revert.

The way I have setup a few environments for web design shops is with a system opposite to what you propose, it works like this:

- All designers work on checkedout copies of sites, and make changes and commit/update as needed.
- On commit, the repository pushes a copy of the site to a staging server, which is configured nearly identical to production.
- If the site is working on staging, there is very high confidence that it will work on the live server.
- When ready, the copy of the site on the staging server can be copied over to live, and now you have updated your site in a very responsible way and you have a history of all of your changes. (For this I like to use rsync, you can make it work however you see fit)

I hope this helps you think about your process somewhat.

Back to your original question: If you really don't want to change your process, you could set up a cron, that runs every few minutes and adds/commits all files that haves changed, and that should work. But I don't like this because now you don't have meaningful commit messages and the change history also might not make sense. As people are working and saving files, they aren't realizing at what point they are being committed, so more than likely there are now revisions in the repository that are a broken state, and now how do you find revisions that aren't broken? Choosing to "automate" the committing is obviously not the cleanest solution.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the best option. It's what I was doing at another company but then I was discplined =)   Hopefully the designers can be convinced to follow this, will layout the benefits. Thanks @ctcherry!

Answer (score 2):

I believe (though I haven't tried it) that you could write an observer for watchdog ( http://packages.python.org/watchdog/ ) that would do the commit for you.

However, I agree with ctcherry that you are going to get a lot of saves in a broken state.  You really need to change your process.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to push for the process ctcherry described.

Answer (score 2):

> CruiseControl and other tools I've
>   looked at don't do this

I would beg to differ. If you were to configure an [`<exec>`](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#exec) block to make a call to the SVN command line tools to commit the code for you, wouldn't that do exactly what you're asking? You can use the [`<filesystem>`](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#filesystem) node to determine which files were modified.

Now, though you could do this, I too agree with @ctcherry that this could cause breaking code to be pushed if you're going straight to production with this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use WebDAV for Autoversioning in Subversion. [Subversion and WebDAV](http://www.tigris.org/scdocs/SVNandWebDAV)

I have used this methodology before.  It is nice in that you can set it up like a windows/linux network share.  Non-technical person just sees it as a network drive to store files on.  Whenever the user saves a document/file there it is silently committed.

Git may have something similar, but I have not experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

On the developer site, you can develop one tool for support this thing, you can see below code, the below code support you how to make Auto Commit on SVN, take a look :)

Any feedback or questions, leave your comment, we can discuss about it

Refer Code here:

```
    public static string AppTitle = "Auto Commit";

    // AddFileToSVN
    public static bool AddFileToSVN(string strLogFile, string path, 
                                         Timer myTimer)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SharpSvn.SvnClient client = new SharpSvn.SvnClient())
            {
                Collection changeFiles = new 
                                Collection();
                client.GetStatus(path, out changeFiles);

                foreach (SharpSvn.SvnStatusEventArgs changeFile in 
                                                     changeFiles)
                {
                    if (changeFile.LocalContentStatus == 
                                       SharpSvn.SvnStatus.Missing)
                    {
                        client.Delete(changeFile.Path);
                        WriteLog(strLogFile, changeFile.Path + " Removed - 
                                 Missing files (that are not in filesystem)");

                        myTimer.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (changeFile.LocalContentStatus == 
                                     SharpSvn.SvnStatus.NotVersioned)
                    {
                        client.Add(changeFile.Path);
                        WriteLog(strLogFile, changeFile.Path + " Added - 
                                   This file is new in filesystem!");

                        myTimer.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
            WriteLog(strLogFile, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // CommitToSVN
    public static bool CommitToSVN(string strLogFile, string workingcopy, 
                                          string message, Timer myTimer)
    {
        using (SharpSvn.SvnClient client = new SharpSvn.SvnClient())
        {
            SharpSvn.SvnCommitArgs args = new SharpSvn.SvnCommitArgs();

            args.LogMessage = message;
            args.ThrowOnError = true;
            args.ThrowOnCancel = true;

            try
            {
                myTimer.Enabled = true;
                return client.Commit(workingcopy, args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myTimer.Enabled = true;
                WriteLog(strLogFile, ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

view more info: from [here](http://learn-tech-tips.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-build-program-auto-commit-source-code-to-svn-in-csharp.html)